# plotting multiple columns value in x-axis in python

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart, seaborn

I have a dataframe of size (3,100) that is filled with some random float values.
Here is a sample of how the data frame looks like

```
     A         B         C
  4.394966  0.580573  2.293824    
  3.136197  2.227557  1.306508    
  4.010782  0.062342  3.629226
  2.687100  1.050942  3.143727
  1.280550  3.328417  2.247764
  4.417837  3.236766  2.970697
  1.036879  1.477697  4.029579
  2.759076  4.753388  3.222587
  1.989020  4.161404  1.073335
  1.054660  1.427896  2.066219
  0.301078  2.763342  4.166691
  2.323838  0.791260  0.050898
  3.544557  3.715050  4.196454
  0.128322  3.803740  2.117179
  0.549832  1.597547  4.288621
```

This is how I created it

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,5,size=(100, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
```

Note: pd is pandas

I want to plot a bar chart that would have three segments in x-axis where each segment would have 2 bars. One would show number of values less than 2 and other greater than equal to 2.

So on x-axis there would be two bars attached for column A, one with total number of values less than 2 and one with greater than equal to 2, and same for B and C

Can anyone suggest anything?
I was thinking of using `seaborn` and setting hue value for differentiating two classes (less than 2 and greater than equal to 2) but then again hue attribute only works for categorical value and I can only set one column in x-axis attribute.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a filter and then count them, then you must use `plot(kind='bar')`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,5,size=(100, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

dfout = pd.DataFrame({'minor' : df[df<= 2].count(),
     'major' : df[df > 2].count() })

dfout.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why someone voted down, but this worked so i am voting up and taking this as an accepted answer

Comment: If you voted negative you should post your motive to be able to improve the post.